# Bootstrap Navbar Image logo resizing with media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to get a logo on the left of my Navbar to resize responsively, I've tried several different methods that I have found on here but I've had no luck. Any help appreciated.

I have @media queries at the moment but they are not working. My code;
https://codepen.io/grabthereef/pen/WKVMEd

HTML

```
    <!--Nav -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top py-1">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="img/ycal.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="?page=why-choose-us" class="nav-link">Why Choose Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="?page=our-services" class="nav-link">Our Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="?page=remote-help" class="nav-link">Remote Help</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="?page=contact-us" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #3292a6;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background: #fff; }
.navbar .nav-item {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding-right: 20px; }

 @media(max-width: 950px) {
  .ycal img {
    width: 264px;
    height: 68px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
  .ycal img {
    width: 264px;
    height: 68px;
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks like a banner image, more than a logo. What's your desired look?

Comment: @onyx It's actually some text with graphics saved as a png file. I just want this image to resize according to the browser window or mobile device screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with `@media queries`. The only reason they are not working in your example is that you are not correctly selecting the images you want to resize.

`.ycal img` selects an image tag inside an element with the class of `.ycal`, but that in your case is already the image you want.

So update the selector and it will work just fine:

```
@media(max-width: 950px) {
    .ycal {
        width: 264px;
        height: 68px;
    }
}
```

You can also check out the [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/luke-codewalker/pen/zLgaGm).

Comment: Excellent. Is this the best way to do it or should I be using Bootstrap tags? ty dude

Comment: You're welcome! I'm not sure what you mean by "Bootstrap tags". Selecting an HTML tag e.g. `img` with CSS will affect all these elements in your page, while using a class like `.ycal` in your example gives you control over which elements will be selected because you can choose which elements you give this class. Hope that answers your question!